# custom js image viewer is loading slower after each "next" key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I've built a custom image viewer that works fine, but each time I use the arrows to view the next or previous image, it loads slower and slower. By the 10th image, it could take many minutes, or even freeze. The snippet I use to open the viewer is the same as the one I use to move to the next image, and each open is always lightning fast; only when I use the arrow keys does it get slower. Sometimes the .php file won't load at all and it'll just say "undefined", which is coming from the JS somewhere, I believe?

```
function image_load(id) {
    $('.view').empty().load(image-viewer.php?id='+id, function() {
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
                var next = $('#next').attr('alt');
                if(next != "null") {
                    image_load(next);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
                var prev = $('#prev').attr('alt');
                if(prev != "null") {
                    image_load(prev);
                    return false;
                }
            } 
        });
    }); 
}
```

So the next/previous reference the function within which their contained. Is it creating an endless loop somehow and slowing down the processor?

Comment: Yes, you're creating an endless loop in the sense that you are calling/referencing the function in itself. Also, there is no need to rebijd key events for every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you are creating an endless loop because you are repeatedly binding the key events over and over again. What you should do is separate the function declaration away from event handlers:

```
var image_load = function(id) {
    $('.view').empty().load('image-viewer.php?id='+id);
};

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    // Prevent default key actions
    e.preventDefault();

    // Evaluate pressed keys
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
        var next = $('#next').attr('alt');
        if (next) image_load(next);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
        var prev = $('#prev').attr('alt');
        if (prev) image_load(prev);
    } 
});
```